# Mysql - fastest way to Insert Update with large interdependent table ( join table )

Tags: mysql, join, optimization, insert, rdbms

I have two table let say

#### Table1:

contain columns
`id , name, email`

*Note : column email has unique constraint*

#### Table2:

contain columns
`id , table1_id, address`

I have extra csv file which contain records of both tables i.e name, email and address, and i want to insert and update those csv rows into table1 and table2 with following scenarios:

scenario 1 - No email exist in table1 insert record in table1 and table2 also 
scenario 2 - If email id already exist it should not affect in table1 but address column of table2 should get update

what is the **fastest and efficient** way to write query to achieve this in MySQL

Comment: Create temporary table. Load CSV into it. Update both tables data (`INSERT IGNORE INTO table1` and `REPLACE INTO table2`). DDL +  3 DML queries total.

Comment: @Akina Thanks. table1 and table2 both are large table. can you specify fastest insert or update query in both tables with considering scenarios which I have explained

Comment: @Akina how can i directly write replace table2 as email id column exist in table1 only

Comment: Data source for the last query which will update `table2` will consist from 2 tables - temporary source table and `table1` joined by `email`.

Comment: @Akina is there any other alternate way you can suggest, without considering any extra table

Comment: No. CSV cannot be used as datasource in MySQL.